# Unable to see Add WhatsApp account in my Facebook business manager

Tags: whatsapp, facebook-business-manager

I had tried to add a WhatsApp account in business manager settings. The guidelines in their helpcenter documentation stated that I could add a WhatsApp account from business manager settings. But in the business settings I could not find the add WhatsApp account button, except the Instagram account button. Is this feature not available in some countries or why would it not appear for some users.